# Confused on DataSet.Merge and RowState

Tags: c#, .net, dataset

Consider the following, oversimplified `DataTable` object:

[image]

`Id` is an autoincrementing integer that acts at the table's primary key, while `Text` is a simple `String` typed column.

Now consider the following code:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var dataSet = new TestingDataSet();

    var row = dataSet.TestingTable.AddTestingTableRow("First");

    dataSet.AcceptChanges();

    var copiedDataSet = dataSet.Copy();

    Console.WriteLine("Row after initialization:");
    Console.WriteLine();

    Console.WriteLine("Text : " + row.Text);
    Console.WriteLine("State: " + row.RowState.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine();

    row.Text = "Modifications";

    Console.WriteLine("Row after changes:");
    Console.WriteLine();

    Console.WriteLine("Text : " + row.Text);
    Console.WriteLine("State: " + row.RowState.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine();

    dataSet.Merge(copiedDataSet, false);

    Console.WriteLine("Row after merge:");
    Console.WriteLine();

    Console.WriteLine("Text : " + row.Text);
    Console.WriteLine("State: " + row.RowState.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine();

    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

That code produces the following result:

[image]

Look at the final `RowState` value. It is modified. How come? The copied dataset instance had no changes, and I explicitely set the `preserveChanges` parameter to `false`. Therefore shouldn't the row now be considered `Unchanged`?

[This MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/magazine/cc164076(en-us).aspx) states that when rows are merged, their state follows as well. Is the article wrong, or is something in my code is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I dug a bit deeper in the documentation and came across this:

> If the incoming row has a RowState of Unchanged and the existing row
>   has a RowState of Modified, Deleted, or Added, the RowState of the
>   existing row is set to Modified.

So it seems that this is the expected behavior when merging unchanged rows into modified rows.

Full article can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aszytsd8(v=vs.100).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue, and ended up getting around it by pulling all changes out of the main DataTable object, running AcceptChanges on the core object, then doing work on the individual tables and merging them back into the main.  That way everything in the core DataTable object is "Unmodified", and will just absorb the RowState of the merged data without any unexpected adjustments like this.